# C++ check if two sequences are equal using a 3rd sequence as criteria

Tags: c++, algorithm, std, equality

I need to check if two given sequences are equal, but if I find a mismatched element I need to check in a 3rd sequence (same size of the other two) if that can be ignored.

I know that I can write a simple algorithm to solve that, but I would like to know if there is any C++-like style to solving this, using a std algorithm.

Example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = [1, 2, 3, A, 5, 6]
M = [true, true, true, false, true, true]
N = [true, true, true, true, true, true]

bool equal1 = the_equal(begin_A, end_A, begin_B, begin_M); // Should return true, even if '4' is different from 'A' since in the same position of the found mismatch, in the M sequence, we have a false that indicates that position should be ignored.

bool equal2 = the_equal(begin_A, end_A, begin_B, begin_N); // Should return false, since '4' is different from 'A' and we have a true in sequence N for that position.
```

That could be solved by something like:

```
template<I1, I2, I3> // iterators
bool the_equal(I1 first1, I1 last1, I2 first2, I3 first3) {
  while (first1 != last1) {
    if (*first1 != *first2 && *first3 != false)
      return false;
    ++first1; ++first2; ++first3;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to say that I need to solve this in c++98 due toolchain limitations :(

Comment: Could this line `if (first1 != first2 && first3 != false)` be `if (*first1 != *first2 && *first3 != false)`? (note the added asterisks for dereferencing)

Comment: what do you want to achive? is it about coding style? i mean even in such a simple example there are probably a lot possible ways to do it, but they probably could look worse than what you already came up with.

Comment: @Arun fixed, thanks.

Comment: @user1810087 I want to know if I'll reinvent the wheel or not. :)

Comment: [FYI] [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) will show you all of the standard algorithms that C++ has.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I checked that before post my question, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a (mutable) functor:

```
template <typename IT>
struct CmpWithMask
{
    CmpWithMask(IT it) : it(it) {}

    template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
    bool operator () (const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs) {
        return !*it++ || lhs == rhs;
    }
    IT it;
};

template <typename IT>
CmpWithMask<IT> MakeCmpWithMask(IT it) { return CmpWithMask<IT>{it}; }
```

And then, use `std::equal`:

```
std::cout << std::equal(A.begin(), A.end(),
                        B.begin(),
                        MakeCmpWithMask(M.begin())) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::equal(A.begin(), A.end(),
                        B.begin(),
                        MakeCmpWithMask(N.begin())) << std::endl;
```

Comment: actually this one is quite nice :)

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 1):

Although `std::equal` is close, it is not clear if it can be directly used. I think your code is quite good. I might rewrite it slightly differently as

```
template<I1, I2, I3> // iterators
bool equal_with_mask(I1 first1, I1 last1, I2 first2, I3 first3) {
  for (; first1 != last1; ++first1, ++first2, ++first3) {
    if (*first3 && (*first1 != *first2)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If in case the (in)equality comparison is heavy, then checking the mask first might be good.

Trivia: The third sequence (`first3`) is like a mask as used in some hardware devices, like Ternary Content Addressable Memory (TCAM).

Comment: Error here `template<typename ...>`

Comment: Yes @Arun, you got the point. The third sequence will be a mask.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Thanks, I used the text from question and modified it. Let me grab a compiler and address the complete syntax in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I also think your code is just fine. You could use one of the standard functions, but it is not always advised, imho, since it can make code less readable. The best solutions is the one YOU can read. However, here a solution (one of a lot possible implementations) using [std::mismatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) :

```
template<typename I1, typename I2, typename I3> // iterators
bool the_equal2(I1 first1, I1 last1, I2 first2, I3 first3) {
  auto p = std::mismatch(first1, last1, first2);
  if(p.first != last1)
    return (!first3[p.first - first1] ? true : the_equal2(p.first+1, last1, p.second+1, first3));

  return false;
}
```

See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a51ddc901d6890b0) in action, and note, not bug checked...

But does it look like a better example than [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39151171/1810087) posted? With the recursion and `auto p` where you have to look up what type `p` could even be if you don't know what mismatch returns (a `std::pair<I1, I2>`)? You can even improve it by using some iterator_traits or fancy find_if/equal/mismatch combinations to get rid of the recursion and to make it even more unreadable.

Comment: A simple loop is sufficient to get rid of recursion.